# What is the correct greeting to use in a formal email addressed to a department/team/company?

Tags: email, formality

If the email were to be addressed to a specific person, you could write "Dear [Name]".

But is it appropriate to write "Dear [Team / Department / Company]"?

For example, "Dear Service Desk," and "Dear Microsoft,".

Comment: Related: [Salutation in cover letter](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3331/), [“Dear Sir or Madam” versus “To whom it may concern”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2112/), and [Addressing multiple recipients in an e-mail](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3700/).

Comment: More to the point, working part-time in support, I see "Dear Support" all the time, and I've also run across "Dear Sales" on several occasions. However, I wouldn't be anywhere as comfortable with seeing or even writing "Dear HR", "Dear R&D", "Dear Finance", or "Dear Marketing" (I would rather go with "Dear Sir or Madam" or just a simple "Hello").

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's within your own company you can use simply "Colleagues,". If specifically your own team, then "Team,". (i.e. no "Dear" or "Hi" needed)

If it's not your place of work, then the usual "Hi" or "Hello" will do.

Comment: Agreed. I see few emails, and write none, which begin "Dear" anything.

Comment: Love "Colleagues" and "Team". Bravo!

Comment: The To and Subject headers largely render the salutation and subject lines of actual physical emails obsolete. I would just begin with the first line; although I would probably not come to the point directly.

Answer (score 3):

The most common greeting I've seen for these types of email is the simple:

> Hi all,