# How to start an official letter to a company (not an individual)?

Tags: american-english, letter-writing

When you send a letter to a person in a company, you start with dear ...,

But how do i start the letter when I'm writing to a company itself, not an individual in there? I don't even know which position in that company will receive the letter.

For example if the company name is google, should i start with Dear google, ...?

Comment: For the record, this was asked before but closed as off-topic https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89881/how-to-address-letter-to-a-company

Comment: Traditionally it's been "Dear sirs", but that's no doubt considered sexist now.